# Determine the derivative of $y$ with respect to $t,$ knowing that $x ^ 2 + 3 = t$

Tags: functions, derivatives

Could help me please.

Let $y = y (x)$ be a differentiable function, determine the derivative of $y$ with respect to $t,$ knowing that $x ^ 2 + 3 = t.$

Comment: What does "Let $y=y(x)$ be a derivative function" mean? Do you mean that $y$ is differentiable with respect to $x$?

Comment: $dy/dt = (dy/dx) /  (dt / dx)$

Answer (score 3):

Let $y=y(x)$ and $t=3+x^2$ so $\frac{dt}{dx}=2x$. Then by the chain rule we have $$\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{1}{\frac{dt}{dx}}=\frac{y'(x)}{2x}.$$